# How to reference an element in an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have recently started learning Java after finding that Python couldn't run the program I am building quickly enough.

My ArrayList is called SO and it is full of objects of the class Organism (this class has a property called immunity). I need to change the immunity property of my Organism objects.

In Python, to reference an element of a list I would simply use:

```
SO[index].immunity = AnInteger
```

but in Java this does not seem to work. How to I do the same thing in java?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is there anything I can change about this question to make it more helpful?

Comment: I think you're getting downvotes because this is the kind of thing you can easily Google or use a basic tutorial for.

Comment: @4castle I Googled for about half and hour and looked at lots of Stack Overflow questions. It turns out that I simply had a misconception about the .get function. It CAN be used to edit the value of an element in the ArrayList after all.

Comment: That's good. You did the right thing then. Next time you could also show what you tried and what questions you referenced that were similar but didn't quite help. If you've already done the research, you might as well benefit from it by showing your work. Research is what makes a great question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an `ArrayList` of `Organism` class the way to define it, assuming you actually have a class `Organism` is:

```
ArrayList<Organism> organisms = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can `add` Organisms to the ArrayList, and access them doing:

```
organisms.get(<index>);
```

where `<index>` is the index of the element in the ArrayList

To change the value of the inmunity property of the Organism in index 3, supposing it is public, would be done:

```
organisms.get(3).inmunity = <new value>;
```

**Note:** get() only retrieves the objec from the list. By no means it changes anything. The change happens when inmunity is assigned a new value.

The last line could also be written like this:

```
// Retrieve the object in the list
Organism org = organisms.get(3);

// Change the inmunity value
org.inmunity = <new value>;
```

As @Zabuza says in his comments, if you need to replace the Organism in the list by a different instance you have to use:

`organisms.set(3,<another Organism instance>);`

Comment: The last part helps. I was unaware that the .get method could be used to change the value of an element in the ArrayList

Comment: get() is actually returning the Organism object, on which the inmunity attribute is being referenced. This could also be acomplished in two steps. Organism o = organisms.get(3); And then, o.inmunity = <new value>;

Comment: @EthanWrightson To be precise the `get` method doesn't change anything at all. You would need to use `organisms.set(index, anotherObject)` to replace the object at the given position with another. The `get` method returns the object at the given position. The object remains *connected* to the list, it is **not a copy**. So if you change properties of the object, since it is **the same** object as the one in the list, the change will be reflected to the list too.

Comment: @Zabuza get() will return the object in the list, if you want to change that obect's inmunity attribute, you can do it directly. What you are showing is how to replace an Organism object instance in the list for a different one.

Comment: @Juan I think OP got confused with the terms. `get` does not change the object. Of course, as I said, if you change properties of the object, the change will be reflected in the list. Since `get` does not return copies but the references to the same objects that it holds internally. If you want to replace an object entirely, you need to use `List#set`, I know that this is not what OP intends to do but I think he would try it with `organisms.get(3) = <new object>`, thus my comment. I'm just stumbling over *"I was unaware that the .get method could be used to change the value"*.

Comment: @Zabuza I had tried to clarify the confusion you mention in my comments, but to make it clear now I have added that clarification to the answer. And also added your point on replacing an instance in the list. Thanks!